# Issue with the mocked service call

Tags: angular, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to check if the particular function calls another function that is called inside it ,but the same outer function also has a service call ,the function is as defined

```
public markAsCompleted() {
    this.dataService.mLCompleted([{ id: 123, isRequired: false }]);
    this.markCompletion();
  }
```

the test case in jasmine that i wrote is as follows

```
it('should check if the markCompletion is called from markAsCompleted', () => {
    const markCompletionspy = spyOn<any>(component, 'markCompletion');
    
    component.markAsCompleted();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(markCompletionspy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

and for the service I had mocked it as follows  in before each

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['mLCompleted']);
    mockDataService.markLessonCompleted.and.returnValue('completed');

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [BaseComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: DataService, useValue: mockDataService }]
    })
      .compileComponents();  //need this if using systemjs for inline styles and tempelate urls
  }));
```

still when i run the test case I get an error saying Cannot read property 'topic' of undefined and it is inside the service ,even though i had mocked the service why would that be an issue,i'm new to jasmine and test cases if anything wrong is being done please guide

Comment: It seems that you simply aren't instantiating the service correctly, use `mockDataService = TestBed.get("NameOfServiceClass");`  in the beginning of `beforeEach` function.

Comment: Where did you try to access the `topic` property?